# .NET Layering naming conventions

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, naming-conventions

I understand naming conventions in .NET e.g. use *Pascal Case* for class names, method names and instance variables and use *Camel Case* for method arguments.  Don't use hungarian notation e.g. prefixing a class with cls or a data type with int or str etc.

My question is; how does this apply to class names in different layers? Some people say segregate them using namespaces e.g. have `com.application.dal.Person` for the *Data Access Layer* person and `com.application.bll.Person` for the *Business Logic Layer* person and others say simply have `PersonDAL` and `PersonBLL` (different class names).

I am wondering what Microsoft suggest with this? I have looked through MSDN and I have not found an answer.